# The Commands of my Discord bot are not working...but the events are working fine

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a Discord Bot...but the commands are not working...only the events are working

If I clear the events...the commands are working....but if the events are there...commands are not working..

Please help me..

Here is my whole code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import sports  #upm package(sports.py)
import random

intents = discord.Intents.all()
Intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents, pass_context=True)
TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN'


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Succesfully logged in as {0.user}".format(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     me = message.content.lower()

     hello_msgs = [
         'hello <@!820999504496820224>',
         'hi <@!820999504496820224>',
         'heya <@!820999504496820224>', 
         'hoi <@!820999504496820224>'
     ]

    bad_words = ['ghost', 'abcd']

    if any(x in me for x in bad_words):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(
            f'''{message.author.mention} BAD HUMAN!! Don't use bad word''')

    for mesg in hello_msgs:
        if mesg in me:
             hello = ['Hello! ', 'Hi! ', 'Hoi! ', 'Heya! ']
             h_msg = random.choice(hello)
            pre_msg = message.author.mention
            se_msg = h_msg + pre_msg
            await message.channel.send(se_msg)


@bot.command(name='kill')
async def on_kill(message):
    await message.channel.send('Police: You are arrested!! Now chill in jail')
    user = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="JAIL")
    await user.add_roles(role)

@bot.command(name='ping')
async def on_ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'My ping is {bot.latency}!')


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Why do you use `on_kill(message)`? Use `ctx` instead. Is the ping command also not working?

Comment: No...no commands are working..

Comment: Try including `process_commands(message)` in that on_message event. Could be possible that your bot ignores the commands otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run the commands and a on_message at the same time.
To make both work, try adding `await bot.process_commands(message)` at the end of your on_message event.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `ctx` to your on_kill command

```
@bot.command(name='kill')
async def on_kill(ctx,message):
    await message.channel.send('Police: You are arrested!! Now chill in jail')
    user = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="JAIL")
    await user.add_roles(role)
```